# Bash: Use variable in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk

I'm in need of some help (again) after you guys helped me wonderfully last time. 
I'm writing a script to test my HDD's with SmartCTL. So I can ofcourse copy the commands per disk, but it would be even more awesome if I can just set the disks once and the script does them one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash
 date=`date +%d-%m-%Y-%T`
 touch /var/log/disk/Disk-health-check-$date
 disks="/dev/sda 
 /dev/sdb"
 for disk in disks
    do
    wait=$(smartctl -t short $disk | awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}')
      echo "waiting..."
      sleep $((wait * 60 + 60))
      echo "done"
      smartctl --log=selftest $disk
      smartctl -a $disk
   done
 exit
```

But unfortunately it only uses the /dev/sda, and not sdb, etc.
So how can I make this works? Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: `for disk in $disks`, not `for disk in disks`. Though even that is bad practice.

Comment: `disks=( /dev/sda /dev/sdb )`, and use `for disk in "${disks[@]}"`, for an array. And fix all the bugs http://shellcheck.net/ finds.

Comment: as another aside -- use `YYYY-mm-dd` as your date format. It's an ISO standard, and -- more importantly -- its ASCII sort order lines up with its sort order as a date, which is absolutely not true for the format you're trying to use here. Having ASCII sort order be correct makes it way easier to find the oldest or newest file, or every file older than a specific date, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for disk in disks; do
  echo "$disk"
done
```

You'll see that the only thing it echos is `disks`. That's because you're telling it to iterate over exactly one value, and that value is `disks`.

---

To do the subtly buggy thing you were trying to do, you want instead:

```
for disk in $disks; do
  echo "$disk"
done
```

However, as I said, that's *buggy*. Let's say your `disks` variable were assigned a bit differently:

```
disks='
/dev/disks/by-label/My Drive
/dev/disks/by-label/Other Drive
/dev/disks/by-label/* TEENAGE DAUGHTER'S DRIVE *
'
```

This would have `/dev/disks/by-label/My` as one entry, `Drive` as the next -- and the `*`s would be expanded to the names of files in the directory you're in when you run the script. Obviously not what you want.

Instead, use an array:

```
disks=(
  "/dev/disks/by-label/My Drive"
  "/dev/disks/by-label/Other Drive"
  "/dev/disks/by-label/* TEENAGE DAUGHTER'S DRIVE *"
)
```

...and iterate over them as:

```
for disk in "${disks[@]}"; do
  echo "Processing: $disk"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty sweet.
Would you mind explaining "${disks[@]}" how that actually works?
I've never seen that before to be honest.

Is there any difference using ("*disks
disk*") or disks=(disk1 disk2)? (Yours and Chuck Donahue's)?

Comment: My answer and Chuck's are effectively equivalent, since the content at hand doesn't *need* to be quoted. `disks=( "/dev/sda" "/dev/sdb" )` would work too, in the case where the names don't contain any spaces or glob characters. I'm showing the quoting above to demonstrate how it works when needed with an array, whereas it *wouldn't* work with `disks='"/dev/sda" "/dev/sdb"'` or such; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a detailed discussion of the failure mode.

Comment: As for `"${disks[@]}"`, that's standard array expansion syntax -- see [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005), or the bash-hackers wiki page on arrays linked from Chuck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T)
touch /var/log/disk/Disk-health-check-"$date"
disks=(/dev/sda /dev/sdb)
for disk in "${disks[@]}"
   do
   wait=$(smartctl -t short "$disk" | awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}')
     echo "waiting..."
     sleep $((wait * 60 + 60))
     echo "done"
     smartctl --log=selftest "$disk"
     smartctl -a "$disk"
  done
exit
```

Based upon Array Variables outlined here: 
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays?s[]=arrays

Comment: Much better. I'd suggest directing logs to stderr rather than stdout -- since they're status (intended for user consumption) as opposed to output (to be sent to the next program in a pipeline) -- but nothing here is wrong on its face.

Comment: Thanks for the link to spellcheck.net

Comment: err, it's "shellcheck", with an h rather than a p :)